# The Jack of Spades (with cider), Jack of Hearts (with tarts) ...

Tags: probability

The Jack of Spades (with cider), Jack of Hearts (with tarts), Queen of Spades (with a wink), and Queen of Hearts (without tarts) are taken from a deck of cards. These four cards are shuffled, and then two are dealt.

a) Find the probability that both of these two cards are queens, given that the first card is a queen.

b) Find the probability that both are queens, given that at least one is a queen.

c) Find the probability that both are queens, given that one is the Queen of Hearts.

- From my lecture notes, I know part A is obtained by ((2/4) (1/3)) / (2/4) which yields 1/3.
- I know part B is obtained by ((2/4) (1/3)) / (1 - (2/4) (1/3)) which yields 1/5.
- Finally, I know part C is obtained by (($\binom{2}{1}$)(1!)(1/4)(1/3)) / (($\binom{2}{1}$)(1!)(1/4)) which yields 1/3.
- However, I do not understand where the numbers are coming from. I am having trouble understanding the logic being used to solve the question. Can someone please explain to me process and logic behind the numbers being used? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do tarts, cider and winks have to do with this?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I have no clue, that is just a part of the question.

Comment: Probability that $X$ happens, given that $Y$ happens, is called a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), written $P(X \mid Y)$, and defined as $P(X \cap Y) / P(Y)$.  Each of your formulas is simply evaluating $P(X \cap Y)$ (i.e. both $X$ and $Y$ happen) and dividing it by $P(Y)$.  Do you have trouble evaluating some of the terms?  If so, which ones?